# User settings and the dirty flag

Tags: c#, settings

I use the standard Settings class. Some of the properties are marked as User settings. I change one of them and then save. In the AppData folder I see that this property is stored in user.config along with one that I did not change. 
How do I know witch properties will be stored? Is there any "dirty" flag on each of them?

Comment: It is an XML file, it stores *all* of your user-scoped settings.  Doesn't matter if just one of them changed, the entire file gets rewritten.  You never care about this, just always call Save().   When your app closes, doing it when you change the setting is risky because you might save a value that causes your app to crash.  It will crash again when you restart.

Comment: Can you give a birds view of the use case to suggest you accordingly

Comment: @HansPassant No it is not, it stores 2 out of 6 properties that I defined in the Settings file. And the behavior is different on the different Windows versions.